# To create comic book, multi page, vector based, free/open source alternative

Tags: vector-graphics

Which software should I use to create a multi page comic book, drawing vector based paths like in inkscape, being free/open source and running on Windows or Linux?

One requirement is that it should be easy to paste a screenshot into a square, then panning/scaling it inside the square (that will clip the screenshot).

Preferrably, the squares would flow with the document.